# Getting JSON from PHP using jQuery into table without appending

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Alright, so I feel like a bit of a doof here... but I had been having problems with AJAX getting data from a PHP-coded JSON page. After figuring out the right combination of PHP code and jQuery code, I now have a working product... Almost!

The problem here is getting new results to populate without repeating the existing data. I know it is because I am using the tr.append method.

*This is the doof part:*

I don't know the proper way of iterating the rows from the JSON page but do not repeat the results on each check, or how to 'translate' my code into  that.

**Here is the PHP code:**

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM incidents2014 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 5");
$rows = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)){
  $rows[]=$r;
}
$b=json_encode($rows, JSON_HEX_TAG);
echo $b;
```

**The JSON output:**

```
[{"id":"1","date":"date1","time":"time1","city":"city1","fire":"fire1","addy":"addy1","level":"level1","desc":"desc1","ipaddress":"ip1","who":"who1","last_update":"lu1","RSS_time":"rss1","lat":"","lng":""},
{"id":"2","date":"date2","time":"time2","city":"city2","fire":"fire2","addy":"addy2","level":"level2","desc":"desc2","ipaddress":"ip2","who":"who2","last_update":"lu2","RSS_time":"rss2",lat":"","lng":""},

etc...]
```

**The jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function get(){
  $.getJSON('jsontest1.php',
  function (json){
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append("<td id='id'>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='date'>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='time'>" + json[i].time + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='city'>" + json[i].city + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='fire'>" + json[i].fire + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='level'>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='desc'>" + json[i].desc + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='addy'>" + json[i].addy + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id='who'>" + json[i].who + "</td>");
      $('table').append(tr);
    }
  });
  }
//  setInterval(get,3000);
});
```

The result *looks* like it should, but the grouping of the above rows repeats itself ever 3 seconds (if uncommented).

I would appreciate *any* and *all* help!!!

Thank you!!! - Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a setInverval, it's just going to keep repeating your ajax call, and your success function will just keep appending every 3 seconds like you've told it to do. You need some sort of check, whether your table already has that row. You could put the id into the tr as a way to check... then, you could just update the text if it already exists, or append it, if it doesn't. Also, I changed your ids to classes since they will be used multiple times

```
$(document).ready(function get(){
$.getJSON('jsontest1.php',
function (json){
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  var tr = $('#+'json[i].id);
  if(tr.length){
    tr.find('.id').text(json[i].id);
    tr.find('.date').text(json[i].date);
    tr.find('.time').text(json[i].time);
    tr.find('.city').text(json[i].city);
    tr.find('.fire').text(json[i].fire);
    tr.find('.level').text(json[i].level);
    tr.find('.desc').text(json[i].desc);
    tr.find('.addy').text(json[i].addy);
    tr.find('.who').text(json[i].who);
   }
  else {
    tr = $('<tr id='+json[i].id+'/>');
    tr.append("<td class='id'>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='date'>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='time'>" + json[i].time + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='city'>" + json[i].city + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='fire'>" + json[i].fire + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='level'>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='desc'>" + json[i].desc + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='addy'>" + json[i].addy + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td class='who'>" + json[i].who + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
  }
}
});
}
setInterval(callAjax,3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function get(){
var check = 0;
$.getJSON('jsontest1.php',
function (json){
var tr;
if(check != json[i].id){
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td id='id'>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='date'>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='time'>" + json[i].time + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='city'>" + json[i].city + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='fire'>" + json[i].fire + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='level'>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='desc'>" + json[i].desc + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='addy'>" + json[i].addy + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id='who'>" + json[i].who + "</td>");
  $('table').append(tr);
  check = json[i].id;
}
}
});
}
setInterval(get,3000);
});
```

Comment: I think I messed up the function names... can you check again in a minute while I fix them and let me know if it changes your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the last ID and send it to php to fetch all records bigger than that.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function get(){
      latestID = $('table tr:last td:first').text();
      $.getJSON('jsontest1.php?id='+latestID,
      function (json){
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
          tr = $('<tr/>');
          tr.append("<td id='id'>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='date'>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='time'>" + json[i].time + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='city'>" + json[i].city + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='fire'>" + json[i].fire + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='level'>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='desc'>" + json[i].desc + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='addy'>" + json[i].addy + "</td>");
          tr.append("<td id='who'>" + json[i].who + "</td>");
          $('table').append(tr);
        }
      });
      }
      setInterval(callAjax,3000);
    });
```

PHP:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM incidents2014 WHERE id > ".$_GET['id']." ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 5");
$rows = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)){
  $rows[]=$r;
}
$b=json_encode($rows, JSON_HEX_TAG);
echo $b;
```

Other way of doing is you can check it all the data in frontEnd with a little help of isInArray function which i found here: [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

```
var IDs = [];
  $('table tr').each(function(){
      IDs.push($(this).find('td:first').text());
  });

  $.getJSON('jsontest1.php',
          function (json){
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
              if(!isInArray(IDs, json[i].id)){
                  tr = $('<tr/>');
                  tr.append("<td id='id'>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='date'>" + json[i].date + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='time'>" + json[i].time + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='city'>" + json[i].city + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='fire'>" + json[i].fire + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='level'>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='desc'>" + json[i].desc + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='addy'>" + json[i].addy + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td id='who'>" + json[i].who + "</td>");
              }
              $('table').append(tr);
            }
          });
          }
     setInterval(callAjax,3000);});
```